# Restart service programmatically when user or system kill it

Tags: android, service, background-service

I have a background service that run for a long time even if my main activity is killed or is in background.

The problem is when:

1. user kills manually the service from *settings--->app--->myapp **force stop***
2. power-intensive mode (ultra mode in Huawei for example) is active

In this case my service was killed and there is no way to restart it automatically.

This is my service code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

  protected final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
  }

  @Override
  public final int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

      Log.i(TAG, "onStarCommand(): Received id " + startId + ": " + intent);
      return START_STICKY;

  }

  @Override
  public final IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return m_messenger.getBinder();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "Service Stopped.");
  }    

  @Override
  public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
    Intent restartServiceTask = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
    restartServiceTask.setPackage(getPackageName());    
    PendingIntent restartPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1,restartServiceTask, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager myAlarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    myAlarmService.set(
        AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
        restartPendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
  }
}
```

Comment: There should be no way to start your service after user wants it to be stopped (via force stop). It is up to the user to choose if he wants your app running or not, not up to you.

Comment: For the Huawei ultra mode? It is a power-intensive battery mode. I have seen that some apps like viber wher I exit from this mode restarted their service automatically

Comment: probably there should be no way as well - this mode is made to decrease battery consumption, and is turned on by user. If the user wants to save his battery - you should not be able to override that. That is up to him again, not up to you.

Comment: Imagine that the user has some emergency, and wants to make his battery life longer. And here comes your service, which is overriding it, and now user's phone is down because of your service, and he gets hurt because of it somehow.

Comment: Your observation is correct but why when I leave the ultra Viber mode it started automatically and my service is not?

Comment: Adding this also, from API 26 (Oreo) all service's must be foreground service which means the user can see your service and will force stop it if required. Hence it is suggested to do your X task in a more acceptable/organic and non hindering way.

Comment: there are probably some hacks to be able to do that. For example sceduling new task to check and start your service using AlarmManaget or JobScheduler. So you schedule the job for every x minutes, which checks if your service is working, and if it is not - starts this service

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko do you have an example of a jobScheduler?

Comment: I don't as I don't use it, but google for sure has

Comment: Do you think that the system don't kill also my "scheduled task"?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I have created both a jobScheduler and then an AlarmManager but if the user or the system kills my app also the alarm and the job are killed.